# customise single product page layout in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I want to have the layout like this in the single product page in woocommerce;

on the left side:

Product Title
Image
in stock
Add to cart

on the right side:

description

can you please help me with this as im pulling my hair out!!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with page layout . It will easy if you have some knowledge of HTML , CSS and php .

You need to create a folder named woocommerce inside your themes folder and copy the contents of the templates folder of the woocommere plugin inside your themes folder. In this way you are able to overwrite the default content.

After completing the above, look for a file content-single-product in the woocommerce folder in your themes's folder. You'll see lots of hooks and do_actions. Don't panic. These are just calling the files from the single-product folder inside the woocommerce folder. In that folder the files are nicely titled and grouped and you'll know what one file is responsible just by seeing the file title. For example price.php for displaying the price, product-attributes.php for product attributes (in case the product is variable).

Play around with these files. If you need the original ones you'll find them again in the woocommerce plugin's folder  .

Its a safe and better way to customize your product page or woo commerce  .

Recommendation -  Never play with woo commerce files inside plugin folder . Copy plugin files in your theme directory before editing and do edit there ..

I am sorry if you did not get your answer .